# Remove id and ? from url to make url seo friendly

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to setup the urls to make it seo friendly.

I have a script that displays some of the urls like this..

```
http://example.com/article.php?id=3456/AnimaliaKingdom.html
```

I’m trying to make the url’s look just like this

```
http://example.com/article/3456/AnimaliaKingdom.html
```

or

```
http://example.com/article/AnimaliaKingdom-3456.html
```

or

```
http://example.com/article/AnimaliaKingdom/3456.html
```

In my .php file, I’m using this location at header

```
header(“Location: article.php?id=$id/$row[name].html”);
```

Here's a portion of the code

```
$res = SQL_Query_exec("SELECT article.id,article.name WHERE article.id = $id");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);

if ($_GET["hit"]) {
     SQL_Query_exec("UPDATE article SET views = views + 1 WHERE id = $id");
         header("Location: article.php?id=$id/$row[name].html");
die;
}
```

This is the Rewrite rule i used

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^article/(.*?)$ /article.php?id=$1 [L]
```

I have used the above Rewrite Rules to redirect the path, but it doesn't seem to work..

I've tried some of the similar questions but don't seem to get any of them working... thanks..

Comment: you have to make links as you wanted "friendly" then rewrite them to php script, making links like that with header is not right thing to do !

Comment: Why do you call `header(“Location: article.php?id=$id/$row[name].html”);`? In this place you should send content to user.

Comment: Have you enabled mod_rewrite? AllowOverride All in your config files? Does your .htaccess generate error when you put junk code in it?

Comment: yes, it does bring up 500 errors...

Comment: without the header it returns a blank page.... I didn't write the script btw..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to make your links in some url class like this:

```
<?php
class Url {
    public function link($type, $id, $seo) {
        return "/$type/$id--$seo.html";
    }
}

$url = new Url();
$link_article = $url->link('article', 100, 'friendly-text');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>testing</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="<?php echo $link_article; ?>">Article 100</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

then with rewriterule redirect them to script, like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\d+) $1.php?id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```